# about sorting arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 arrays (A,B,C) and A has its own integer 10,and C has its own integer 8 and B has its own integer 5  and how can I sort arrays with its integers and then return those arrays??
it means that you sort integers : 5,8,10 and I want to return their arrays : B,C,A
how can I do this? please help me thanks

Comment: Is this homework? Are the arrays guaranteed to contain exactly 1 element? If not, how do you define their sort order in general?

Comment: this is not my home work I have found these integers for those arrays and then I sort those arrays with these integers but I do not know that how can I return their arrays?

Comment: but what if they contain more than one element? Could you have A {5, 10}, B {6, 11}, C { 1, 6} ? What would you return then? I think you need to define the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

> I have found these integers for those arrays and then I sort those arrays with these integers but I do not know that how can I return their arrays?

You can't return 3 objects from a method. Instead, you could put them in an [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in the desired order and return it as [`List`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html). E.g.:

```
class MyArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {
    public int compare(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
        int sn1 = getThatSpecialNumber(a1);
        int sn2 = getThatSpecialNumber(a2);
        if (sn1 == sn2)
            return 0;
        else if (sn1 < sn2)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

List orderArrays(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    list.add(c);
    Collections.sort(list, new MyArrayComparator());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? Collections.sort returns void, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "has its own integer", but you can store them into i.e. `java.util.ArrayList` and then search for the value, i.e.:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
....
int number_we_are_searching_for = 12345;
int i = 0;
YourArray a = null;
while(i < list.size())
{
    if(list.get(i).SomehowRetrieveThatNumber() == number_we_are_searching_for)
    {
        a = list.get(i);
        break;
    }
    i++;

}
```

**EDIT:** Or add them in desired order (sort them while adding).

Answer (score 0):

```
final int[] a = { 10 }, b = { 5 }, c = { 8 };

// put them in an array. (a List<int[]> works too)
int[][] arrs = { a, b, c };

// sort them using a custom comparator
// (Change "Arrays" to "Collections" if you used a List above)
Arrays.sort(arrs, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return ((Integer) o1[0]).compareTo(o2[0]);
    }
});

// Print result and return it:
for (int[] arr : arrs)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

return arr;
```

#### Output:

```
[5]
[8]
[10]
```

Comment: I need arrays to be my out put instead of these numbers how can I do this?

Comment: `o1[0] - o2[0]` may overflow with large values, giving incorrect result.